# jmeter proxy recording duplicate request

Tags: proxy, jmeter, performance-testing

I am currently using JMeter to record a test scenario with the HTTP test recorder proxy.
Problem is, when I send a request with IE on my application, the recording controller gets flooded with an unlimited number of duplicate requests corresponding to the one I just sent.

[Multiple requests when accessing default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmL3N.png)

Any idea about why this could be happening is welcome.
Have a good day

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder should be accurate enough and if you see extra requests most likely they happen.

I would recommend double checking what's going on on network level between IE and application under test [Using Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If it reproduces in IE without JMeter proxy - it might be an integral part of your application, i.e. it does periodic [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) for updates using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) calls which needs to be reflected in your load test as well.

If not - you need to  find the reason why does JMeter behave this way starting from [enabling debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for JMeter proxy. It can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So after hours of setting comparison and http request analysis, I found out it was just the "type" parameter of the HTTP Test Script Recorder that needed to be set to "Java".

Hope this can help someone.
Don't forget to have a good day :-)